# 3rd inner while loop not working

Tags: java

In the blow code the inner 3rd while loop not working please tell me why ?
Here I tried with for loop by replacing the 3rd inner while loop it is working correctly but why not working with while loop .....? can you give me genuine reason...?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MergeArray {

    void arrayInitialization(Scanner arg) {
        //entering test cases
        System.out.println("enter test cases");
        int t = arg.nextInt();
        int k, l, i;
        k = 0;
        l = 0;
        i = 0;
        //outer while loop
        while (t-- > 0) {
            //initializing a1[]'s size
            System.out.println("enter a1[]'s size");
            int as1 = arg.nextInt();
            int a1[] = new int[as1];
            //inner while loop-1
            while (as1-- > 0) {
                System.out.println("enter a1[]'s elements");
                a1[i] = arg.nextInt();
                System.out.print(a1[i]);
                i++;
            }
            i = 0;
            //initializing a2[]'s size
            System.out.println("enter a2[]'s size");
            int as2 = arg.nextInt();
            int a2[] = new int[as2];
            //inner while loop-2
            while (as2-- > 0) {
                System.out.println("enter a2[]'s elements");
                a2[i] = arg.nextInt();
                System.out.print(a2[i]);
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            int a3[] = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
            int size = as1 + as2;
            //inner while loop-3
            while (size-- > 0) {
                if (k < a1.length)
                    a3[l] = a1[k];
                if (k < a2.length)
                    a3[l + 1] = a2[k];
                k++;
                l += 2;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < (a1.length + a2.length); j++) {
                System.out.print(a3[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MergeArray ma = new MergeArray();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System. in );
        ma.arrayInitialization(sc);
    }
}
```

I tried so much but not found solution. Here I am using while loop because I know that while loop will work fast instead of for loop.

Comment: Why do you init those arrays inside of a while-loop?

Comment: When searching for debugging help, please always clearly state what your code is supposed to do and what it is currently supposed to do. Otherwise we need to deeply dig into your code just in order to understand what your code is even supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you are decrementing the sizes of `as1` and `as2`. Which will be

```
 int size = as1 + as2; // size = 0 + 0;
```

Instead you can make use of the array length e.g.

```
int size = as1.length + as2.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Murat K's Answer is right, but try to init the arrays like this:

```
        //init a1
        System.out.println("enter a1[]'s size");
        int a1[] = new int[arg.nextInt()];

        //fill a1
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter element " + i + " of a1[]");
            a1[i] = arg.nextInt();
        }

        //init a2
        System.out.println("enter a2[]'s size");
        int a2[] = new int[arg.nextInt()];

        //fill a2
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter element " + i + " of a2[]");
            a2[i] = arg.nextInt();
        }

        //init a3
        int a3[] = new int[a1.length + a2.length];

        //merge a1 and a2 into a3
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
            a3[i] = a1[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
            a3[a1.length + i] = a2[i];
        }

        //print
        for (int i : a3) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
```